# How to create sqlite database in online storage?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to make a app that adds data to local SQLite database and uploads data to a database so other people that use the app can download that data. I thought about loading SQLite database to online storage but I do not know how to do that or what the best way is.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what kind of answer are you expecting. Complete code? That's unlikely, there would be a lot of code. Whether it's a viable design? Yes, it's viable. Clarification on one of the aspects of the architecture (Web service, Android app, database, Web hosting) - which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the simple approach:

```
Your app <--->PHP webpage <----> sqlite (on server) --->url of SQLite to download
```

Your app need to connect to a web api, such as PHP, that can handle `sqlite`. You can perform `sql` operators via the api and then get the `sqlite` file by simply using its URL.

[Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1.First create sqlite database

2.then create oracle database

3. Setup Apache server like xampp. After setup open php.ini. then delete ; before oci8.dll. then save.
4. C:xampp/htdocs create php webservice .

5.Call php webservice from android for download upload data.

If you can't I will help you